# Manual Install of Restkit, without cocoa pods

Tags: ios, git

I've followed the Git submodule guide for Manual Restkit install, however I want to have control over which Restkit version I install, that installation was done for IOS 8.

I'm currently trying to install to IOS 7 project, and want to use the Restkit 0.25.0 version. I changed the Podfile produced and ran *git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git* again
but got a 'RestKit' already exists in the index' message.

Does any one know how to specify the Restkit version to use in a Manual Install, I'm trying to avoid cocoapods for install.

Comment: is there a reason for iOS7 and avoiding pods? you can specify versions in pods. you can also checkout a specific commit in your submodule.

Comment: Hey @rmaddy, did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: @ERullmann You should ask the OP. I just made an edit to the question.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. @HitmanHearns, did you manage to find a solution to the problem? Thanks.